# I have two signals, recorded from the same device. How do I standardize/normalise them?

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum, machine-learning, deep-learning, array-signal-processing

I essentially have two signals X and Y, recorded with PPG devices. These have been filtered already. I want to standardize(z-score) or min-max scale them but I don't know if I should do this on each signal individually, or combine them (This is my main question). I am then calculating the STFT to calculate the power spectral densities in segments for my ML model.

Comment: why would you normalize them? That would mean whatever you do doesn't work on your original signal but a modified one, where you removed a lot of the important info – especially since you're interested in **power** spectral densities, I'd say this is counter-productive.

Comment: I observed that the spectrogram does not change after standardization. Yet, the power spectral density values are smaller.

Comment: https://enzokro.dev/spectrogram_normalizations/2020/09/10/Normalizing-spectrograms-for-deep-learning.html

https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6579/abf9f3/pdf

Some resources that I used.

Comment: yes, but for a reason, not "just because", so why do you want to normalize, if you're actually interested in the PSD, and not something else.

Comment: For the exact same reason that those resources did it. For my particular ML application, I need to have inputs that are distributed between 0 and 1 or have 0 mean and std of 1. Spectrum normalisation is even more challenging and thus I am going for this approach. My question is what method of normalisation is more appropriate i.e. how to apply it on the data.

Comment: The problem here is that it's impossible to tell you what is appropriate without understanding what your purpose is; you just "define" you need values between 0 and 1, but that doesn't seem to be motivated by your goal, but by the structure of the network you're choosing, right? I haven't read the page in full there, but the author of it also kind of skips the part *why* they're normalizing. Might be obvious to you why they are doing that, but it's really not obvious to me. Could you try to explain that?

Comment: In the context of deep learning networks, normalization as the OP is suggesting leads to better and faster convergence (e.g., https://towardsdatascience.com/why-data-should-be-normalized-before-training-a-neural-network-c626b7f66c7d)